# Locally testing Google API Client watch events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the [google api ruby client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) to add a webhook to a calendar but I'm running into a `Google::Apis::ClientError: pushWebhookBadDomain`.

I've set up an ngrok instance and verified it on webmaster tools so that I could add it as an allowed domain to the project that's handling all the calendar auth, etc. I can't find any reference to that specific error so I'm wondering if there's something funky with using ngrok for that and if there are any better ways to go about testing the webhooks locally.

Here's the call (condensed for clarity) in case I'm doing anything stupid:

```
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
client = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :authorization_uri =>
    'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  :token_credential_uri =>
    'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
)
authorization.client_id = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
authorization.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
authorization.grant_type = 'refresh_token'
authorization.refresh_token = refresh_token
authorization.fetch_access_token!
client.authorization = authorization

channel = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Channel.new(address: success_callback_url, id: channel_id, type: "web_hook")
binding.pry
webhook = client.watch_event('primary', channel, single_events: true, time_min: Time.now.iso8601)
```

Comment: Did you follow all the steps mentioned here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push?hl=en .Is your webhook call back URL is HTTPS or HTTP? You can also test in the push notifications playground https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/

Comment: Yep followed all of that and the main issue with any of those playground sites is that it's not using my app, and as the problems I've been having have been related to allowed sites and other app-specific properties I don't get useful information.

Comment: My primary curiosity is if this all boils down to ngrok's ssl cert being bad (as deemed by google) and if someone else has a better way to set this up locally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you registered the domain as an Allowed Domain in the Google Cloud Console for your AppEngine project, you should not include https:// in front of your domain name. You need to register it as xxxxxxx.ngrok.io.

I had the same problem as you and after removing the https:// when adding an Allowed Domain, I'm able to receive Push Notifications on my local machine forwarded using ngrok.

Let me know if that helps you.

Br,
Ethan

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much that did the trick! I feel like a dummy for not thinking of that.

Comment: I wrecked my brains for 4 hours figuring this out. Documentation / prompts in the App Engine Push settings screens could be more precise to be helpful. Or, we could be the only 2 who is special enough not have figured it out ;)

Comment: @EthanS Would you be so kind and tell me how did you manage to get your xxxx.ngrok.io domain verified in Google Cloud Console?

Comment: Hi @astronaut .... where are you stuck at? Without details, I'm gonna have to assume that you clicked on the "Add Domain" button in the "Domain Verification" tab in "Credentials". This didn't work for me. Instead, I added my ngrok domain through https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en

Comment: @EthanS Yes, this is where I got problems. You can't just add a domain in there, you have to verify it in a non-intuitive way. How did you do that?

Comment: @astronaut Use this link: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en
Add both https://????.ngrok.io and http://?????.ngrok.io

Comment: What's the issue that you are facing @julestruong?

Comment: Does this still work for you? Did you get such sophisticated verification requirements for your tmp domains back then?